# scan.addcolumn or qualifierfilter to retrieve values

Tags: hbase

To retrieve values of a specific column in Hbase, should I use `scan.addcolumn` or `qualifierfilter`?

Which method gives better performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know the qualifier, then you must use `scan.addColumn()`. If you are not sure about the qualifier and you want to compare the qualifier with a particular value (using operators like greater, less, equal etc), then you must use QualifierFilter. It is mentioned in the HBase documentation of QualifierFilter-

> If an already known column qualifier is looked for, use Get.addColumn(byte[], byte[]) directly rather than a filter.